# Перенести ветку из одного репозитария в другой

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Есть репозитарий. Создал ветку, сделал какие-то правки.

После этого проект был разбит на модули, код вынесен в отдельный проект, отдельный репозитарий. Все правки в моей ветке, фактически, теперь относятся к одному из модулей. Теперь если в мастере основного проекта посмотреть, вообще таких файлов не будет, какие есть в моей ветке.

Теперь не знаю, как мне быстрее всего "перенести" ветку. Вижу пока только простой вариант - открывать в IDEA основной проект, перейти в ветку, скопировать во временную папку мои файлы. Затем открыть уже проект с модулем и туда скопировать все изменённые файлы.

Но как-то выглядит это не совсем правильно что ли.

Comment: Самое простое - схлопни в один коммит и удали из коммита лишние файлы, сгенерь патч и примени в нужном репозитории, либ о запуш в другую репу

Comment: Добавляешь другой проект, где эти файлы есть, потом делаешь rebase относительно ветки из этого проекта своей ветки, устраняешь конфликты. Потом merge. Делов-то!